# Check the last exit code of a command echoed by a bash script

Tags: bash, return-value, expect

```
#!/bin/bash

test(){
        return 1;
}

VAR=$(expect -c 'puts "Exiting"; exit 1;');
echo "$VAR";
RETURN_CODE=$?;
echo $RETURN_CODE;

test
RETURN_CODE=$?;
echo $RETURN_CODE;
```

The output of this script will be:

```
Exiting
0
1
```

My guess is that the first 0 is the return code of "echo". Am I right? If so then how do I capture the return code of `expect`?

Comment: I guess you already understand this, but doing explicit `exit 1` will of course always give you exit/return value `1`. Also, if you have a script that doesn't have a exit/return statement at the end, it's return value will be the same as the last executed command/function's return value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exit/Return code needs be extracted immediately after running any command.

So use:

```
VAR=$(expect -c 'puts "Exiting"; exit 1;')
RETURN_CODE=$?
echo "$VAR"
echo $RETURN_CODE
```

Since your code is doing `echo` right after `expect` call therefore `$?` is giving you exit status of `echo` rather than the `expect` command.